# I can't access Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, boot, windows-8

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 but I can't reach it. The boot page doesn't appear and I can't choose which OS I want to use. It goes directly to Windows 8.

Comment: I guess you installed windows after ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Probably is the windows bootloader installed, you have to replace that one with grub, you can do this with [Resc-A-Tux](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/)

This is a live cd with a primary goal: Restoring grub/installing grub. It's a nice program which I used after windows just removed my grub without asking, and it worked like a charm.

When you boot it up, a popup pops up. In this popup you can select install/repair grub. Select this, it will ask some stuff, but if you click ok, it will install grub as it is always installed as default.

A small tip: Always install Windows first, since Windows just throws away grub without asking.

> **Rescatux features:**
>
> Fixes GRUB and GRUB2
>
> Regenerates Debian/Ubuntu grub menues
>
> Check and fix filesystems
>
> Fixes Windows MBR
>
> Blank Windows passwords
>
> Boot Info Script
>
> Change Gnu/Linux password
>
> Regenerate sudoers file
>
> **Extra tools:**
>
> Synaptic
>
> Gparted 0.7

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.  The solution, which worked for me, is to install a program called 'Boor Repair' using your Ubuntu browser.  For Instructions on how to get this free program and what to do when you've done so, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228434/how-do-i-boot-hp-pavilion-g6-to-display-grub2-00-rather-than-opening-windows8-by/229133#229133).  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this and I can confirm this worked for me and other computers

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

then find the line #GRUB_GFXMODE delete the number sign (uncomment) and replace the resoltion with 1024x768 save it

then run `sudo update-grub`

so sorry I misread your question you cannot boot into ubuntu my mistake