# How do I boot HP Pavilion g6 to display GRUB2.00 rather than opening Windows8 by default?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows-8, bootloader, hp-pavilion

With a lot of help from Ask Ubuntu, I have successfully installed 12.10 onto an HP Pavilion g6 2240sa notebook to create a dual boot machine which also has Win8. This could only be achieved by a full BIOS/GRUB installation (not WUBI).    If I press Esc on boot up I can get into BIOS, access GRUB2.00 and select Ubuntu.  If I do not access BIOS on start up the machine runs straight through to WIN8 making Ubuntu inaccessible.  I want to switch the machine on and have it boot through to a menu offering Ubuntu 12.10 as first choice without forcing Win8 on me.  How do I do this?  I had one idea - to install the Ubuntu Boot assistant from the Installation DVD in the Windows environment - but I'm afraid to mess things up by installing this software after having installed Ubuntu.  How can I ensure that I boot to an OS option menu (default preference Ubuntu - of course!) when I switch the machine on?  Here are my installation [details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227149/how-do-i-install-12-10-on-a-pavilion-g6-laptop-with-uefi)

Answer (score 1):

I have succeeded in booting to GRUB2.00 with Ubuntu by first default option but with Win8 as an option.

I tried the 'Ubuntu Boot Assistant' as postulated in the question - but it did not work.

The solution is:

- Open Ubuntu
- Download and install a program called **Boot-Repair**
- Run the 'Recommended Repair' option

  Boot-Repair cannot be accessed from Ubuntu's Software Center :-(

For full instructions on how to download and install the software see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).  I used the Terminal option and it worked just fine.