# Cannot dual boot Ubuntu 12.10 with windows 8.

Tags: 12.10, windows-8

I have tried automatic partition, i Have did the partition myself but Ubuntu installs alright. But when i restart the computer it goes back to windows 8 and i Have tried easybcd 
boot manager but it didn't work either. I displays ubuntu on the dual boot screen but after a while the screen shutdowns and say it didn't find the boot file or the boot file was missing?

Do you guys know how to solve this problem? any suggestions?

Comment: Could you explain more your trouble? After turn on your computer you go to Windows **directly**? Right now you have the `GRUB` as Boot Manager or what? If so, what happens exactly when you select `Ubuntu` there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 system](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-system)

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu with Windows 8 you need grub 2 bootloader because of secure boot of Windows 8. As I know only grub 2 can boot both. As DrA7 sayed, open Ubuntu Live session (from disk or usb) and install Boot-Repair. Then open this tool. This will repare your boot loader and after reboot you will be able to select both Ubuntu and Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). There are detailed instructions on the site.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have the answer for you as I recently went through exactly the same thing.  You need to follow exactly three (non-techie) steps in precisely this order:

- Access your BIOS (or whatever your computer's initial boot up software is called) and disable the 'Secure boot' option.  You also need to configure it to boot from USB in priority before the C: drive.
- Install Ubuntu from a properly prepared USB boot stick (NOT DVD/CD) and NOT from WUBI which does not work on some UEFI 64 bit systems. This will allow you to call GRUB2.00 which offers Ubuntu as first choice when you boot the computer - it also gives you a Windows 8 option too.  [Read and follow these details carefully](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227149/how-do-i-install-12-10-on-a-pavilion-g6-laptop-with-uefi).
- Install and run the Boot Repair software that other solutions are recommending.  This will allow your PC to access GRUB2.00 directly without Windows 8 stealing the show on boot up. [This is how I did it by following expert guidance from others](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228434/how-do-i-boot-hp-pavilion-g6-to-display-grub2-00-rather-than-opening-windows8-by).

Good luck!