# Windows 8 doesn't recognise Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 8 installed Ubuntu 12.10 boots straight to Windows 8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231098/windows-8-installed-ubuntu-12-10-boots-straight-to-windows-8)

I've managed to install Ubuntu 12.10 on my computer. The BIOS recognises it, the Live USB recognises there's an installation but Windows 8 doesn't. I have disabled safe boot in the BIOS. How can I boot into Ubuntu with the Windows 8 boot menu?