# No option to boot into Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I'm new to ubuntu and linux in general and I needed ubuntu installed for university purposes. My laptop has windows 10 already on it and I wanted to dual boot it with ubuntu 18.04.

I got through the whole installation phase of ubuntu through a live usb, (I assigned my own partitions for ubuntu to use) and when I got to the end of the installation, it asked to restart, so I did and it then never gave me a grub screen for me to choose what OS i wanted to use, instead it just automatically booted into windows 10. I have no idea what to do beyond here. I had secure boot and fast start up disabled, and I followed this websites tutorial:

https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/

I believe it may have something to do with me needing to change the UEFI boot order but I have no idea how to access it as every tutorial I watched to get there has a different bios screen to what I get.

Please help, my heads starting hurt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 8 installed Ubuntu 12.10 boots straight to Windows 8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231098/windows-8-installed-ubuntu-12-10-boots-straight-to-windows-8)

Comment: You followed a guide for a version no longer supported, 14.04. Download the ISO file for the version of your choice at https://ubuntu.com/download or https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours . The ISO file should be checked for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 . IMaking the LiveUSB once verified is typically done following these instructions on another Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0 or on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 .

Comment: Once you make a LiveUSB, install it following these steps https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0 and when you get to step 6, you will be presented with the choice to install alongside Windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Comment: @K7AAY I just finished trying that and I have garnered the same response, it just auto boots into windows still

Comment: Please shut down Windows by clicking on the Start button, click on the Power icon, press-and-hold Shift, and while holding down shift, choose Shut down. I am trying to make sure Windows turns off completely. If that does not work, see https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup

Comment: I fixed it, it was what I said the first time, I just needed to change the UEFI boot order.